# Why does the ProcessPoolExecutor ignore the max_workers argument?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I expected that a `apscheduler.executors.pool.ProcessPoolExecutor` with the `max_workers` argument set to 1, would not execute more than one job in parallel.

```
import subprocess

from apscheduler.executors.pool import ProcessPoolExecutor
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler


def run_job():
    subprocess.check_call('echo start; sleep 3; echo done', shell=True)

scheduler = BlockingScheduler(
        executors={'processpool': ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)})

for i in range(20):
    scheduler.add_job(run_job)
scheduler.start()
```

However actually up to ten jobs are executed in parallel.

Do I misunderstand the concept or is this a bug?

Comment: Did you create more than one such executor by any chance? Seeing the code might help.

Comment: You need to give a more complete example -- one I could run myself. For one, are you sure you're specifying the correct executor to run with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this isn't working as expected is because you're not specifying which executor you want to run the job in.

Try this instead:

```
for i in range(20):
    scheduler.add_job(run_job, executor='processpool')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Is it possible to prevent the Scheduler from adding the default executor?

Comment: No, nor should it be. But you could define your own executor as "default".

Comment: Would you care to elaborate on this a little bit? Obviously I'm misunderstanding something about the concept of apscheduler.

Comment: You named your executor "processpool" but if you name it "default" it will be used by default without having to explicitly specify the name in add_job().